# node keys wonky cannot access json object via key after upgrade

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, redis, publish-subscribe

I have a node application which is successfully receiving a request from a publish from redis

redis_client1.on("message", function (channel, message) {

```
 logger.debug("sub channel " + channel + ": " + message);
```

which correctly logs

> 20:23:15 - debug: sub channel LoginChannel: {'username': u'user6',
>   'user_id': 9}

and if I JSON.stringify it also correctly logs

> 20:23:15 - debug: Login from redis, adding user to users "{'username':
>   u'user6', 'user_id': 9}"

but when I log the keys

```
logger.silly(Object.keys(message));
```

I get this weird output and I cannot access the json object like this message.username which used to be working until I updated node to version 8.2.1

> 20:23:15 - silly:  0=0, 1=1, 2=2, 3=3, 4=4, 5=5, 6=6, 7=7, 8=8, 9=9,
>   10=10, 11=11, 12=12, 13=13, 14=14, 15=15, 16=16, 17=17, 18=18, 19=19,
>   20=20, 21=21, 22=22, 23=23, 24=24, 25=25, 26=26, 27=27, 28=28, 29=29,
>   30=30, 31=31, 32=32, 33=33, 34=34, 35=35, 36=36, 37=37, 38=38, 39=39,
>   40=40, 41=41, 42=42, 43=43, 44=44, 45=45, 46=46, 47=47, 48=48, 49=49,
>   50=50, 51=51, 52=52, 53=53, 54=54, 55=55, 56=56, 57=57, 58=58, 59=59,
>   60=60, 61=61, 62=62, 63=63, 64=64, 65=65, 66=66, 67=67, 68=68, 69=69,
>   70=70, 71=71, 72=72, 73=73, 74=74, 75=75, 76=76, 77=77, 78=78, 79=79,
>   80=80, 81=81, 82=82, 83=83, 84=84, 85=85, 86=86, 87=87, 88=88, 89=89,
>   90=90, 91=91, 92=92, 93=93, 94=94, 95=95, 96=96, 97=97, 98=98, 99=99,
>   100=100, 101=101, 102=102, 103=103, 104=104, 105=105, 106=106,
>   107=107, 108=108, 109=109, 110=110, 111=111, 112=112, 113=113,
>   114=114, 115=115, 116=116, 117=117, 118=118, 119=119, 120=120,
>   121=121, 122=122, 123=123, 124=124, 125=125, 126=126, 127=127,
>   128=128, 129=129, 130=130, 131=131, 132=132, 133=133, 134=134,
>   135=135, 136=136, 137=137, 138=138, 139=139, 140=140, 141=141,
>   142=142, 143=143, 144=144, 145=145, 146=146, 147=147, 148=148,
>   149=149, 150=150, 151=151, 152=152, 153=153, 154=154, 155=155

Comment: what if you use the current version of nodejs? perhaps 8.2.1 was broken

Comment: I justed tested node 6.x and same issue, I reverted to version 0.12.x and it works again.

Comment: That's interesting. What version of node_redis are you using?

Comment: I was referring to the current 8.4.

Comment: I have tested with 8.4 and I am using redis v.2.8.0, I tried a typeof and received string, however, I cannot JSON.parse because I get a SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1

Comment: I was able to get around this issue by turning my json object into a string before passing it to redis and then doing a JSON.parse on the string in node.